# При выводе половины символа не выводится результат

Tags: php, ideone

Этим кодом http://ideone.com/OvEDUG

```
<?php
echo "\xD0\xBA\xD0\xB0\xD0\xBA";
```

выводится слово

```
как
```

Но если я добавлю вывод без последнего байта http://ideone.com/B17xrO

```
<?php
echo "\xD0\xBA\xD0\xB0\xD0\xBA";
echo "\xD0\xBA\xD0\xB0\xD0";
```

то получу успешное завершение и сообщение

> Standard output is empty

Куда вывод делся?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хм.. Подумал с запустил такой же код на си. Получился тот же результат.
**Вероятно, это какая-то проверка, встроенная в сам ideone**, а не ошибка в программе.

http://ideone.com/te8Y20

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  puts("\xD0\xBA\xD0\xB0\xD0\xBA");
  return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/1iJ7lG

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  puts("\xD0\xBA\xD0\xB0\xD0\xBA");
  puts("\xD0\xBA\xD0\xB0\xD0");
  return 0;
}
```